# Setting up a Fabric network on multiple computers: Unable to instantiate chain code on peers of 2nd Org

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, ibm-blockchain

I am trying to setup the balance-transfer network on multiple computers.

This is similar to the query at

[unable to Instantiate any chaincodes on peers of newly Added org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50078637/unable-to-instantiate-any-chaincodes-on-peers-of-newly-added-org)

However, there was no resolution to that question

My approach is described below:

1 Org1, Orderer, CA1 on 1st computer
2.Org2, CA2 on 2nd computer
3.Split the docker-compose file accordingly
4.Added the IP's in the network-config file

I was able to register users of both Orgs and install chain code on both the hosts. However, I am not able to instantiate the chain code on Org 2 (ie. the second computer)

I get the following error :

> [2018-07-19 11:20:31.401] [ERROR] instantiate-chaincode - **REQUEST_TIMEOUT:10.228.27.96:8051**
>   [2018-07-19 11:20:31.402] [ERROR] instantiate-chaincode - Error: **ChannelEventHub has been shutdown**
>       at ChannelEventHub.disconnect (/Users/digital3/Desktop/Final/balance-transfer/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/ChannelEventHub.js:444:21)
>       at Timeout.setTimeout (/Users/digital3/Desktop/Final/balance-transfer/app/instantiate-chaincode.js:101:10)
>       at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
>       at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
>       at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5)
>   [2018-07-19 11:20:31.403] [ERROR] instantiate-chaincode - **Error: ChannelEventHub has been shutdown**
>       at ChannelEventHub.disconnect (/Users/digital3/Desktop/Final/balance-transfer/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/ChannelEventHub.js:444:21)
>       at Timeout.setTimeout (/Users/digital3/Desktop/Final/balance-transfer/app/instantiate-chaincode.js:101:10)
>       at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
>       at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
>       at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5)
>   [2018-07-19 11:20:31.403] [ERROR] instantiate-chaincode - Failed to instantiate. cause:Error: ChannelEventHub has been shutdown
>   (node:3837) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: **Failed to instantiate. cause:Error: ChannelEventHub has been shutdown**

From what I understand, the proposal is sent to orderer but fails there.

The peer logs suggest the same: **Failed connecting to orderer.example.com:7050 Could not connect to any of the endpoints**

Could someone help me with this? Should I add any extra-hosts parameter in the docker-compose file for ORG2. I have only included the IP's in the network-config files for now.

Docker compose for ORG 2 is shown below

```
ca.org2.example.com:
image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
environment:
  - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
  - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org2
  - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem
  - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/a7d47efa46a6ba07730c850fed2c1375df27360d7227f48cdc2f80e505678005_sk
  - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
  - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem
  - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/a7d47efa46a6ba07730c850fed2c1375df27360d7227f48cdc2f80e505678005_sk
ports:
  - "8054:7054"
command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d'
volumes:
  - ./channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
container_name: ca_peerOrg2
```

peer0.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org2.example.com

```
extends:
  file:   base.yaml
  service: peer-base
environment:
  - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org2.example.com
  - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
  - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051
ports:
  - 8051:7051
  - 8053:7053
volumes:
  - ./channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer
```

peer1.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org2.example.com

```
extends:
  file:   base.yaml
  service: peer-base
environment:
  - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org2.example.com
  - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
  - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org2.example.com:7051
ports:
  - 8056:7051
  - 8058:7053
volumes:
  - ./channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer1.org2.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer
```

Comment: How are you trying to set it up on multiple hosts what are the tools that you are using?

Comment: I added a extra hosts parameter in the docker containers of ORG 2. This points to the orderer sitting in the first computer. Is there anything else i should do?

Comment: There has to be an overlay network established between your hosts is that done?

Comment: @SuryaSuresh Please post your instantiate command and the output of "printenv" command from a peer of 2nd Org